# Does an initially accelerating electron introduced inside a homogeneous magnetic field reduces its spin magnetic dipole moment?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, dipole-moment

Due to the Lorentz force we know that such an electron will be forced to a helical forward trajectory and given enough time inside the magnetic field it will experience also a continuous diminishing helical radius (i.e. [gyroradius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroradius)) since it is radiating EM waves therefore loosing kinetic energy and linear speed therefore Lorentz force reduces thus also the gyro radius.

The above is the accepted explanation I believe, however I am wondering if a more deeper fundamental cause results to this above phenomenon and characteristic trajectory path other than the electron's radiation?

What if the accelerating electron is varying its [spin magnetic dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment#Spin_magnetic_dipole_moment) during flight from its rest value? This argument is further supported if despite the reduction in the gyroradius  the angular velocity of the gyro rotation remains fixed?

Comment: At the end of this motion the electron is at rest, again. Can I measure the dipole moment of a resting electron? Yes. The first time I did that was in an ESR experiment in an experimental undergrad physics class. I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: @FlatterMann Yes, we measure always the magnetic moment of the free electron very close to one Bohr Magneton at rest. But what about during flight?

Comment: Yes, I can measure it in flight, too. That's called the Stern-Gerlach experiment. I still don't understand your question.

Comment: After exhaustive search of the literature these last days, it seems that this question has not a simple answer and concussion and corrections are made on the experiments for the rest frame especially the g-2 synchotron where however the SG force is also present.  Please review the following literature: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02111 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01825 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06858 and also this related PSE question  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/734052/has-been-the-spin-magnetic-dipole-moment-value-of-the-free-electron-to-be-lorent

Comment: We know the literature. None of it is in support of your hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Due to the Lorentz force … it will experience also a continuous diminishing helical radius (i.e. gyroradius) since it is radiating EM waves therefore loosing kinetic energy and linear speed therefore Lorentz force reduces thus also the gyro radius.

The last part of the sentence is a bit confused. It is more accurate to say that the reduction of the kinetic energy of the electron occurs because it emits photons during its (helical) deflection. What exactly is cause and what is effect?

One attempt at an explanation is the following:

1. the external magnetic field acts on the magnetic dipole of the electron and aligns it with its field.
2. photons are emitted from the electron (choose a different time for the emission and see if this is consistent with the phenomenon of the Lorentz force).
3. Because of the photon emission the electron is deflected, loses kinetic energy and the magnetic dipole is thrown out of alignment.
4. the process continues as long as there is still kinetic energy.

> … however I am wondering if a *more deeper fundamental cause* results to this above phenomenon and characteristic trajectory path other than the electron's radiation?

The above explanation is a deeper, more detailed description of the mechanism of the Lorentz force. It does not require any change in the value of the magnetic moment. Incidentally, I am of the opinion that the magnetic moment of the electron is just as fundamental a quantity as the charge of the electron.

Comment: Hi. Thanks that is a good answer. "Because of the photon emission the electron is deflected, loses kinetic energy and the magnetic dipole is thrown out of alignment.". Since the magnetic part of the Lorentz force is a product of the velocity vector and speed of the electron, the slower the speed of the electron the less the Lorentz force that is why my description. "...is radiating EM waves therefore loosing kinetic energy and linear speed therefore Lorentz force reduces thus also the gyro radius." is IMHO equivalent with yours.

Comment: quote: "Incidentally, I am of the opinion that the magnetic moment of the electron is just as fundamental a quantity as the charge of the electron." The g-factor is and so also the FSC α and charge value -e. Nevertheless, as stated by Flatterman herein all measurements of the spin magnetic moment value of the electron  are done indirectly and at rest either measuring the g factor in a synchrotron (i.e. electron constant speed thus at rest) or in the SG experiment  (i.e. electron hitting a screen thus at rest). That what is under investigation is what is the magnetic moment during flight?

Comment: If the spin magnetic moment is not invariant but dynamic with acceleration value inside the external magnetic field this would probably give a non-linear reduction relation of its gyroradius. Furthermore, a constant angular velocity of the decaying radius helical motion would suggest a dynamic spin magnetic moment with translational speed on the x-axis. My argument under consideration is that the spin magnetic moment value of the electron is dynamic and reduces with translational speed on the x-axis and reaches at its maximum value when electron is at rest and stationary.

Comment: Is there an experiment that can test this hypothesis? And what about my other sub-question about if  despite the reduction in the gyroradius the angular velocity of the gyro rotation remains fixed? Anyone to confirm or falsify this?

Comment: I have upvoted your answer however I will mark an answer as best answer only when it proves that the spin magnetic moment value of the free electron NOT at rest is invariant and the same as its rest value about one Bohr Magneton μ(B)=9.274x10^-24 J/T.

Comment: Maybe I should start  a new question and be more specific of what my question is.

Comment: New question created asking more specific what I am asking:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/733827/is-the-spin-magnetic-dipole-moment-of-the-free-electron-not-at-rest-the-same-as

Comment: Since there is no other answer here I decided to tick this answer as the best answer although not really an extended answer about what I really wanted to ask about if the spin magnetic dipole moment of the electron is a constant for a free electron not at rest. Surely the rest value is a constant I agree. But is it really a constant when the electron is not at rest? This is the deeper question  and therefore I started a new question shown in the link in the previous comment.