# Is the spin magnetic dipole moment of the free electron not at rest the same as its rest value?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, dipole-moment

As far as I know all experiments measure the **rest value** of the *[spin magnetic dipole momen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment#Spin_magnetic_dipole_moment)t* of a free electron indirectly (i.e. apparently there is yet no method or apparatus to directly measure this tiny force) measuring for example the g-factor (e.g. in a synchrotron experiment) for the electron *at rest* *(i.e. at constant translational speed)* at about one [Bohr magneton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_magneton) .

But what about the spin magnetic dipole moment of a free electron **not at rest** during for example an accelerated flight?

What proof experimental or theoretical I am not aware of, we have in the literature that the spin magnetic dipole moment of the electron remains fixed and invariant at its rest value of about one Bohr magneton, $μ_{Β}= 9.2740100783(28) \times 10^{-24} J/T$ **when the electron is not at rest?**

Answer (score 0):

The Stern-Gerlach experiment does measure the magnetic moment of electrons "in flight". The precision measurements of the anomalous magnetic moment of muons are also being performed "in flight".

Comment: @Markoul11 I can't even remember how many times I have been voted down, even for perfectly correct statements about all kinds of things. If negative feedback bothers you, then science is not a good place to be for you, I am afraid. It is all about skepticism, after all.

Comment: " The precision measurements of the anomalous magnetic moment of muons are also being performed "in flight". Yes this is true can indirectly calculated from the the anomalous magnetic dipole moment of the electron by measuring the g-factor n a synchrotron however let me remind you that this particular experiment is not testing my hypothesis since the muon or electron is measured at constant speed therefore at rest. On the other hand the inhomogeneous field of of the SGM experiment has the potential for an translational accelerated speed magnetic moment.

Comment: @Markoul11 The electrons in a Stern-Gerlach performed on Earth are all experiencing a 1g acceleration.

Comment: Can you give me a specific literature reference of how the magnetic moment at rest is calculated from the spatial outcome of the SG experiment  quantization of of spin in space thus the familiar "eye" pattern on the detection screen?

Comment: @Markoul11 If you read the rules for this website, then you will find that this is not a homework help site. So, no, I am not going to do your homework and look for literature references for you. If this topic fascinates you, then we all expect you to do the necessary work yourself. That is how real scientists behave, after all.

Comment: "If negative feedback bothers you, then science is not a good place to be for you, I am afraid. It is all about skepticism, after all." Firstly,  the question was downvoted long before any comments appeared or answer so  hyportnex was justified in asking why this question was downvoted without any feedback unless one regards as feedback the votes alone which is not very fruitful attitude and PSE does not encourages this and actually  suggests  to give feedback when downvoting and secondly why downvoting a question which asks for valid information or clarification? I find this at least stupid!

Comment: In general I believe downvoting a question is not fruitful and nonsense and promotes malevolent behavior. A question should be either upvoted or not voted at all or  flagged for many reasons and easily closed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140169/discussion-between-flattermann-and-markoul11).

Answer (score 0):

After exhaustive search of the literature these last days, it seems that this question has not a simple answer and concussion and corrections are made on the experiments for the rest frame especially the g-2 synchotron where however the SG force is also present.

Please review the following literature:

- [Electric and Magnetic Dipoles in the Lorentz and Einstein-Laub Formulations of Classical Electrodynamics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02111) (2015)
- [Relativistic Dynamics of Point Magnetic Moment](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01825) (2017)
- [Muon (g-2) Technical Design Report](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06858) (2015)
- also this related PSE question  [Has been the spin magnetic dipole moment value of the free electron to be Lorentz invariant ever experimentally verified?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/734052/has-been-the-spin-magnetic-dipole-moment-value-of-the-free-electron-to-be-lorent)