# Has been the spin magnetic dipole moment value of the free electron to be Lorentz invariant ever experimentally verified?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, experimental-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, dipole-moment

As far as I know all experiments measure the **rest value** of the *[spin magnetic dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment#Spin_magnetic_dipole_moment)* of a free electron either indirectly at relativistic speeds near the speed of light measuring for example the g-factor in a synchrotron at constant translational relativistic speed at about one [Bohr magneton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_magneton) or at non-relativistic speeds directly as a split distance of the quantized  electron magnetic moment hitting a detection screen at the Stern-Gerlach experiment.

However, the synchrotron relativistic measurement is measuring the g-factor and not directly the magnetic moment force as a split distance as we have in the case of the SG experiment. My argument is that the synchrotron experiment is unsuitable to verify any invariance of the spin magnetic moment of the electron at relativistic speeds compared to non-relativisitc since it relies indirectly at the measurement of the g-factor that has proven many times that is a Lorentz invariant parameter in a vacuum.

Is there an alternative experiment method than can measure directly the spin magnetic dipole moment of the electron as a spatial displacement like the SG experiment without the use of the g-factor but at relativistic speeds that will prove experimentally the invariance of the spin magnetic dipole moment of the electron with translational relativistic speeds (i.e. Lorentz invariant)?

Or is actually the spin magnetic dipole moment of the electron not Lorentz invariant and a Lorentz correction must be applied in such a hypothetical experiment that would calculate its rest value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The magentic  dipole moment is part of a skew symmetric Lorentz tensor $M_{\mu\nu}$ which is defined  so that the interaction with an electromagentic field is $\propto M_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$.   What is called "the magnetic dipole moment vector" has components  $\mu_i= \epsilon_{ijk} M_{jk}/2$  where $i,j,k$ are the spatial indices measured in the rest frame of the particle. A moving dipole aquires  an electric dipole character through the components $M_{i0}$ becoming non-zero after the boost. All this is taken into account in the theory behind the $g-2$ measurements.

Comment: Thank you very much for this canonical answer.

Comment: to answer the " experimentally verified?"  example the LEP experiments depend on this theory formulation  for their electron and positron beam positions  in the collider. The accuracy achieved in the measurements is depended on the formulae of the theory, whchi then is experimentally verified.

Comment: @annav Sorry, but I don't think we can resort to a definitive simple conclusion  to this. Please review the following references:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02111 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01825